# Creating environment in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, navigator

I am new to python and I am having issues with creating environment in Anaconda Navigator having error below.
I updated anaconda navigator through terminal using conda update anaconda-navigator and it went smoothly and successfully, I also hit Update index.. But looks like still some updates are missing.
Does anybody have some advice what to do? I am using MacOS 11.7.8

```
`My error when creating new environment for Python and R:
LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
- package r-base-3.6.1-hcb44179_0 requires readline >=7.0,
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ python 3.11** is installable with the potential options
│ ├─ python 3.11.0 would require
│ │ └─ readline >=8.0,│ ├─ python [3.11.0|3.11.2|3.11.3|3.11.4|3.11.5] would require
│ │ ├─ ncurses >=6.4,│ │ └─ readline >=8.0,│ └─ python 3.11.7 would require
│ └─ openssl >=3.0.12,└─ r-base 3.6.1** is not installable because it requires
├─ krb5 >=1.16.1, │ ├─ krb5 1.16.1 would require
│ │ └─ openssl >=1.0.2o, │ ├─ krb5 1.16.1 would require
│ │ └─ openssl >=1.1.1a, │ └─ krb5 1.16.4 would require
│ └─ openssl >=1.1.1d, └─ readline >=7.0, ├─ readline 7.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
└─ readline 7.0 would require
└─ ncurses 6.0* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.`
```

Comment: Seems like a rather old version of R. How are you creating this "new environment for Python and R"?

Comment: I am choosing 3.6.1 version of R, the newest one from the bar. I create it through Navigator --> Environments --> Create --> then choose both packages Python version 3.11.7 and R 3.6.1.

Comment: Seems like you are right,  I just tried to create it just for Python and it worked.

Comment: You may want to create the R environment first (it looks like this is the more "picky" one. Then see what is the latest version of python that you can install (try 3.11 first, then 3.10, the 3.9 ... see which one works). https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/packages/using-r-language/